# Prism.js overrides font-family CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I am using prism.js to syntax-highlight the code in a series of articles about three.js that I have been writing.  Works great EXCEPT that no matter what I do, I can't seem to override the font family.  The code is always rendered in Courier. I don't like Courier - too heavy and hard to read (IMO).

I created a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/richardkylewright/vqnLkunu/8/) demonstrating this.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.6.0/prism.js"> </script>
<style>
    pre {  
       font-size: 90%;
       font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace; 
}
</style>
```

```
var gfxScene = new GFX.Scene( {
    cameraPos : [-13, 10, 30],
    alphaBuffer: true,
    defaultLights: false,
    controls:true,
    clearColor:0x4444aa,
    shadowMapEnabled:true,
    displayStats: true
    });
```

It looks like prism.js deliberately overrides the font-family specification, but perhaps I am just missing something. (It's happened before ;-)

Comment: Courier is a monospace font. My best guess is you're browser is using Courier as your monospace font after it falls back from Lucida (probably pretty common on Microsoft)

Comment: This is true, but the question is why would the browser "fall back" at all?  Lucida Sans Typewriter is available on my system and if I select it in Chrome as my "default" monospace font, it all works as expected.  But if I have Courier as my "default" font, then that is used even if my CSS says otherwise. And that font selection works in the body text, but not in the prism.js selector-code. This seems like a bug to me.  The <pre> selector should override the "default" font if I understand CSS selector rules correctly (which the browsers may not apparently honor).

Comment: Can you use !important in your CSS property or perhaps include `style=font-family` in your markup?

Comment: Adding !important helps me: 
font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace !important;